# Simple solution to let you know if you have not locked your closed door

Tags: doors, security

I am wondering how is it possible that there's no popular solution yet, for letting you know if you have forgotten to lock your exterior door.

I am not talking about a door left open - I am talking about door being left closed, yet unlocked.

I am often in a hurry and I am forgetful. This is why I need some sort of alarm or at least an indicator, about the door being left unlocked.

(Also, I do not any specific locking mechanism in mind, I am asking in general.)

Is there any simple low-tech solution for this? (High tech solutions are also welcome, though.)

Comment: You could improve the question by explaining how your door works. These things seem to be different over the world - for example in Germany outside doors usually always require a key to be opened from outside, so are "soft locked" by default; but you can use the key from the outside to "lock them even more" if you so wish. For such a door, your question would make little sense, so you likely have a different model. Which is it?

Comment: @AnoE Unless you actually have one of those fancy self-locking multipoint locks, that "soft locked" state is pretty much not locked at all, as it can be defeated in a few seconds in many different ways.

Comment: Sure, @TooTea, the focus of my comment is for OP to improve his question, not on the security of my personal door. ;)

Comment: @AnoE Sure, but I read your comment as claiming that the "question would make little sense" for the typical German door, which is IMHO not true (and could mislead people into thinking they can rely on that "soft locking", which is at best only marginally better than leaving the door ajar).

Comment: @TooTea, I guess we're going slightly off-topic now, but IMO every door/lock that is not specifically designed (and paid for) to be high security is little better than leaving it slightly ajar against a determined burglar, IMO. I personally treat locked doors as valid against snooping neighbours or misguided but harmless adolescents, at best. For everything else, the LockPingingLawyer wants to have a word. OP did not ask about the *security* of a locked door...

Comment: I actually did something like this -- I wanted to be able to verify a door was locked but not with a smart lock that could be hacked. While this in general works for IOT with a contact sensor, you could also replace the IOT reader with an led or something.
 https://old.reddit.com/r/SmartThings/comments/7knv0o/how_i_added_a_read_only_deadbolt_sensor_to_my/

Comment: you could mount a beam-break or reflective (deadbolt plungers are shiny) presence sensor into the deadbolt hole, so that the sensor state reflects the locked status.

Comment: @dandavis Why isn't the answer to "Simple solution to let you know if you have not locked your closed door" simply  "try opening it once outside" not sufficient?

Comment: @ chux - because the question refers mainly to the forgetful guy use case. I tend to forget to lock doors or even when I lock them, I do not remember if I really did so, which is distressing.

Comment: @drabsv: No part of that sounds like it would prevent you from just trying to open it. Are you trying to *remotely* tell whether you locked the door, once you've already left the house?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica That's what I do.  When I leave and at night before bed, I attempt to open the door.  If it opens, I know it is not locked.

Comment: @ user2357112 - I wish there was a way indicating that the door is left unlocked as soon as I close it.

Comment: @drabsv: Then just try to open it as soon as you close it.

Comment: @ user2357112 - the use case scenario is about someone being forgetful and in a hurry - if I could be sure I would not forget to open it as soon as I close it, as you are advising, then I'd probably be sure I would not forget locking it either, on the first place :))

Comment: "In a hurry and forgetful". Sounds like a friend of mine who drops her keys wherever, then spends an hour looking for them. The 100% guaranteed solution is to stop telling yourself you're "forgetful" and _train_ yourself to change your behavior. You'll find benefits all throughout your life by learning to not be "forgetful". Sure, you'll mess up a couple of times along the way, but the effort will be worth it in the end.

Answer (score 13):

OK, so you have a *keyed entry* type doorknob on the door. It has a slot for a key on one side, and a "push or twist" thingie on the other side.

You step outside and close the door, and now you don't know if it's locked, yes?

You didn't say whether the door also has a deadbolt, a common feature on many doors.

### Use good practices. Always lock from the outside.

In my world, that's easy since all our doors have both a keyed-entry lock and a deadbolt (keyed the same). **Our rule is we only use the deadbolt**. We never lock the keyed-entry lock.

So if we step outside and close the door, is the house locked? Easy and sure answer: NO, because you didn't lock it!

So turn around and lock it and now you know it's locked.

Also, when this becomes habit/discipline, it becomes almost impossible to lock yourself out of the house lol.

If your house doesn't have a deadbolt it can probably be added. Any competent locksmith can key it to your existing house key. A few locksmiths have an actual retail store you can walk into.  That's where I prefer to do business. It's *incredibly cheap* since no service call is required. I get lock-sets re-keyed for $20-30 and pay $50-60 for a whole deadbolt set. (quality class 2 stuff, not that rubbish from the box store).

You can also do the same trick with pure discipline.  Simply stop doing that thing where you twist the inside knob as you step out.  Never do that (except to lock the door while you are inside).  Always lock it with the key.

Or, you can do the same trick with the twist-to-set keyed entry locks, simply by using discipline - never twist the twisty thing on the way out the door, only lock it with a key from the outside.

Comment: Hey @harp.   You and I agree on most things but in this case I believe you are over thinking this. In my answer below is a very reliable, low tech solution, not expensive.   Your suggestion of changing behavior is unrealistic and prone to failure.

Comment: Once you get old enough, this simply Does Not Work. You get outside and ask yourself, "Did I lock the door?" and the answer is, "I haven't the foggiest clue". So you go and lock it, go a few steps and ask yourself, "Did I lock the door?" and the answer is, once again, "I have no idea, was that today or yesterday?" Rinse and repeat until you give up and leave.

Comment: Never, *ever* use the twisty thing on an outside door. **Get rid of it** (or disable it, depends on the type of lock/knob). It provides less security than the cheapest deadbolt but leads, far too often, to self-lockouts. One of the very first things when moving into my house many, many years ago was to change the deadbolts and disable the twisty things. (The other was to [replace switched receptacles with ceiling lamps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2DGqVbTHX-k) as I very much disagree with Technology Connections on that one.)

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact: totally agree with you about switched outlets. Every single one of the so-called advantages he cites would be achieved by having both a ceiling lamp *and* a table/floor lamp, each one controlled by its own proper switch.)

Comment: @manassehkatz it has its uses, mainly SOP in police encounters. Cops want to talk to you, you flip it, step outside and pull the door behind you and it's locked.  Now they have no standing to search your home (unless they already had a warrant, or you say something incredibly foolish).

Comment: Fortunately the most serious encounters I've ever had with police were speeding tickets (and usually at speed trsps, and last was many years ago). But I can see how that could be useful for some people.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson I know that one, the problem is it's super easy to lock yourself out lol. Then you're outdoors in your bathrobe rooting around in your neighbor's garden trying to find your hidey-key.  My way makes it impossible to leave the house without your key!

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica  Hope we don't get snipped for getting conversational here, but that happened to me!  First night in a brand new duplex, double checking the doors where locked, in my underwear, at midnight, went into the garage to make sure the garage doors were locked, a bit nervous being quite young so double checking.  The garage was attached so there was a door from the duplex to the garage.  I went to re-enter the living space and found the door was locked!  H. E. double hockey sticks. One choice:  I put a shoulder to the door, broke the jam so I could get back in. ....continues..

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica  I was the first tenant in this duplex, so no blaming anything on anyone else!   To fix it, I got some Titebond II a few clamps and glued it back together, good as new, couldn't see the damage.  When I moved out the inspection didn't notice the damage because it was practically invisible after the repair.   Now I always keep a key in the garage for the door into the house!  Lesson learned!  Thanks for your response.

Comment: I specifically [disable the twist-to-lock tab](https://www.instructables.com/Prevent-Your-Doorknob-From-Locking-You-Out/) on all my exterior doors to avoid this exact problem. No accidentally leaving it unlocked *or* locking yourself out.

Comment: My current home has all dead bolts or those troublesome 3 point locking mechanisms that Pella put out for a few years (top, bottom and deadbolt), maintenance nightmare.Both require keys to lock from the outside.

Comment: @manassehkatz Everyone should be trained on correctly interacting with police.  Innocent people most of all, because that's where the biggest injustices happen.  It's like Damage Control training in a Navy ship - you hope you never need it, but if you do, it saves your bacon.

Comment: "So turn around and lock it and now you know it's locked." is insufficient as it is not clear that "lock it" step was done correctly.  A typical test is to simply test by attempting to open - but I think OP is trying to avoid that.

Comment: My house has six exterior sliding doors; the sliders latch only from the inside. Because of their locations, the sliders are not used when leaving the property.  Two regular doors (front door and office door to the driveway) are used when leaving the property; both those doors have dead bolts, and their knobs _do not contain keyed-entry locks_.  Problem solved.

Comment: @chux Disagree, that's only a problem first few times using a new door. Then you get a feel for resistance and how far the key needs to turn. You'll feel it, believe me.

Comment: This is precisely what I did after I locked my keys in the car for the 2nd time in my life. I _NEVER_ lock my car from the inside. I always wait until I'm out of the car, with all the doors closed. Then, and only then, do I hit the lock button on the remote. If the remote's in my hand with the doors closed, I _know_ I haven't left my keys in the car. I was in my 40s the second time I locked keys in the car, so it's also possible for "old" people to learn new habits. (I was 19 the first time I did it - RKE hadn't been invented yet.)

Answer (score 6):

The problem with high-tech solutions is cost and reliability. Simply not necessary except when it comes to high-value situations (bank vaults, server rooms, etc.)

As far as low-tech solutions, you lose the remote capability. So what most people do is simply try to open the door after locking it. If it doesn't open, you locked it correctly.

What I find is the complication is people who use double locks - i.e., one lock that is a deadbolt (or equivalent) and one that is a simple lock.

When it isn't my decision, I lock the deadbolt first, test the door (turn knob and push or pull the door - if it doesn't open, it is locked) and then lock the other lock and test (usually just seeing if the doorknob will turn or not).

When it is my decision, I remove/replace/disable the non-deadbolt lock. It adds very little security but at the risk of (a) thinking you locked the deadbolt (by locking both without checking the deadbolt separately) and (b) locking yourself out (depending on lock design).

A simple solution might be to have something similar to the "Occupied"/"Unoccupied" signs on single-stall public bathrooms. But those are typically simple slide mechanisms, which might not be easy to adapt to a secure (e.g., deadbolt) lock. Plus that would advertise to anyone walking by that the door is unlocked if you forget to lock it.

Comment: When smart locks(or similar) are mentioned, always think of a video where a guy has voice control lock and comes back home in the pouring rain after having a root canal.

Comment: It doesn't take too long to train yourself to always test the door after you leave.  Closing the door, locking it, and testing it becomes a single fluid operation that quickly feels weird if you skip a step or get interrupted.  You get to where you can do the whole thing on autopilot.  Muscle memory is a strange beast.

Comment: @bta Agreed. Works really well for home - close door, lock door, check door, go to car. But at my office there have been many times where I set alarm, close door, lock door, check door, listen for alarm exit sound...go down elevator, out front door of office building...and think: did I set the alarm? did I lock the door? Back up the elevator...lather, rinse, repeat.

Answer (score 5):

Some of the electronic locks have a timed-exit feature, which relocks the door N minutes after opening it. Then you don't need to check; you can just trust that it will be locked. Downside is that it may lock on you when you just dithered a bit too long, but you do have your keys with you, or a keypad on that side of the door, right? (Little is more embarrassing than a locksmith locked out of his own home.)

Fancier solutions use door-position monitoring rather than or in addition to the timeout, but use the same electric bolt mechanism to actually lock up. That avoids having the lock extend the bolt when you've deliberately left the door open (which tends to result in a thud when you forget that has happened and go to close the door).

Comment: I use the auto-lock feature on my August smart lock and it's great.

Comment: I hate it but it's what the OP is after, +1.

Comment: The alternative is a spring latch with an electric release strike. Still requires a keypad or other secure mechanism to activate it, and harder to install.

Comment: Or, even more expensively, a strike with a sensor.

Answer (score 5):

Low or no tech solution would be simple behavioral training.

Each time you exit try to open the door like you forgot something.

High tech solution would be a doorbell camera.

Then you can see yourself locking or not the door.

Additionally if you forget to lock the door, it will alert you of unfriendly visitors.

Comment: ...or friendly visitors!

Comment: I would think high tech solution would be a lock with wireless connectivity that will actually tell you if it's locked or not.

Comment: @MichaelMior but it is not so much fun

Answer (score 4):

You can get locks, or in some cases set locks which have multiple modes, that are **always** locked when the door closes. Then you'll need to remember your keys...which should be easy after two or three lockouts and whatever that costs you in terms of calling someone holding your extra key, or a locksmith, etc...

Comment: This is the exact reason why I am researching smart locks - I have children so the theoretical construction falls apart quickly. "Researching" because I want to build my own, for all kinds of good and bad reasons.

Comment: This locksmith's solution -- though I have a smart lock too -- is to simply leave a spare key with a trusted neighbor who is usually home.  If I lock myself out, I walk two blocks to pick it up and return it to them later. Besides, their kid is my usual cat-sitter.

If you really don't have anyone you can trust, or find asking for help painfully embarassing, or are just a gadget freak, that's when smart locks are worth considering.

Answer (score 2):

My son's new apartment has Smart Locks. They have a number pad and you input your number. You can program other numbers as well and get a report on your phone as well as alerts when the code is used to unlock the door. You can lock and unlock the door from your phone as well. I believe there is also a function where the door locks it's self when closed for a period of time.
I have no idea of the cost, but it sure is a cool system.

Comment: Many of these are unfortunately quite flawed in design - either they're physically/mechanically badly designed or the electronics is actually easily fooled / bypassed.

Comment: This is definitely not one where you want to go with the cheapest option. Personally I use the August smart lock and I've been pretty happy with it. Mechanically, there are no vulnerabilities introduced by the lock since it simply replaces the deadbolt tailpiece.

Answer (score 1):

I have often thought about solutions for this as I have a few doors that could benefit from it, using different mechanisms.

My thoughts so far have been that it would be possible in most cases to modify the door/lock & mechanism slightly and add a little indicator (a bit like on public lavatory doors with the red/green ENGAGED flag) or if you're feeling flashy, a low-power blinking LED and small coin cell with a simple microswitch or reed switch & magnet to blink to remind you.

Exact mechanics would vary with the door & lock type / mechanism and your available resources in terms of tools, skills, materials.

Answer (score 1):

Simple hi-tech solution: a camera.

Buy a cheap home security camera and point it at the door lock from inside, so that you can clearly see which direction the deadbolt knob is currently pointing from the video feed. You can add a cheap telephoto lens meant to clip/suction onto cell-phones to extend placement options. You might want it to have an IR-emitting ring of LEDs on it to see in the dark, which is a common option, or enhance the visibility of deadbolt handle using colored tape for best results.

While it doesn't immediately give you a digital value you can feed into your overall automation setup, though ML or careful digital image processing could provide that, it will give you a way to check from anywhere to see if the door is locked.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it depends on your definition of "high tech". I personally don't find bluetooth/wifi/smartphones high tech anymore, since they are so common. So I'll tell you what we have:

We have a Schlage Z-Wave keypad entry. It works with google home, amazon alexa, and Samsung Smartthings. With smartthings, we can program it so that if both people in the home leave (based on wifi connectivity to our home wifi), then the lock will automatically lock if it's not already locked. You can also program it so it will lock at a certain time of day, which we have it do at night just in case someone forgets to lock it.

It's a unit like this (the schlage is selling for $470 now, up from $160, holy inflation batman!)

[https://www.amazon.com/Connected-Technology-Featuring-SmartKey-Security/dp/B09HR85FVP/ref=sr_1_4?crid=IM8U30GJI7U8&keywords=deadbolt+zwave&qid=1670359071&s=hi&sprefix=deadbolt+zwave%2Ctools%2C115&sr=1-4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09HR85FVP)

As far a locking, it couldn't be easier, you leave the house, and you press the big button. You only need the code to enter.

I'm not sure what you're looking for with a "lo-tech" solution. Are you wanting to light a light or make a sound?

Update:
To unlock, the model we have came with 2 preprogrammed 4-digit codes. You can also program temporary codes through the app (e.g. you have a dog walker coming by). It also have a physical key to lock and/or unlock. With the SmartThings, it will also record when the door was locked and unlocked, and which code was used.

Comment: Just curious - does this setup let you unlock the door without a physical key?

Comment: Yes, it's a 4 digit code. I've updated my answer with additional details.

Comment: "I'm not sure what you're looking for with a "lo-tech" solution. Are you wanting to light a light or make a sound?" - I don't have any specific expectation, just open to any reasonable idea.

Answer (score 0):

I'd get one of the locksets that is always locked, then hide a key outside someplace in case you forget to take your keys with you.

Comment: I would _never_ hide a key outside. It's only marginally better than leaving the house unlocked. You think you have a unique hiding place, but burglars know them all. The real problem though is that, at least in the UK, insurers won't pay out if there is no sign of forced entry. It just isn't worth the risk.

Comment: Leave a key with a trusted neighbour/local friend instead of hiding it

Comment: If you don't have someone you know enough to trust them with a copy of the key, i have resorted to leaving a copy in your car, if you have one. Admittedly not as safe, but it works.

Comment: That's called a *storage room* lockset.

Comment: CLearly this issue has generated quite a few comments and a lot of the opinions here are probably based on geographic location.  I live in a rural area surrounded by trees.  It would pretty safe for me to put a nail in a tree in the woods and hang a key from it.   In a more suburban setting,  yeah, you'll have to get more creative.  The days of putting a key under the welcome mat are long gone.   Maybe taped with duct tape to the side of a foundation vent?    Apartments would be the hardest to find a hiding place for a key outdoors. I look forward to other comments and ideas.

Comment: Key custody safe mounted to the exterior of the house? You can securely mount them to a concrete pad or a structural member to prevent the safe itself from being stolen, and good ones are rated to resist covert compromise for an extended period of time. 

It won't stop a burglar with a thermal torch from cutting it open, but neither will your front door. And if you mount it somewhere with line-of-sight to the street they won't be able to physically compromise it without drawing attention to themselves.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson at my old apartment building people solved that by hiding a key next to a different apartment. With 21 apartments nobody was going to try every key in every door.

Comment: Keep the key in your garage or external tool shed, etc, so that you can retrieve the key without anyone being able to see what you're doing. Unless you're being majorly targeted by a stalker or pro, it will be far less obvious than say, tilting a flower pot next to the door before walking inside...

Comment: Brainstorming on places to leave a key is getting outside what Stack Exchange is for... and remember that by publishing your idea here you may be telling others where to look for your key, which isn't exactly good security.

Comment: No need to hide a key https://www.homedepot.com/p/KeySafe-Mounted-2-Key-Lock-Box-with-Pushbutton-Combination-Lock-001004/202266076 frame mounted and always there.

Answer (score 0):

Fit a spring to do door, so the door will not remain closed unless locked.   Removal anything from the door that will keep it closed other then the lock.

Another option is to have a **very** loud alarm that sounds if the door is left unlocked for more then one minute. (Needing to call out an expensive company to reset the alarm before it will stop sounding would improve this)

Both of these have in common that they increase the *cost* of not locking the door so much, that forgetting to lock it is no longer an option.

Comment: Most doors I know of that have a lock also have a simple turn knob/latch that, even if it is not lockable, will hold the door in place. Plus there may be times where you don't want the door locked but do want it closed - e.g., expecting guests but it is rainy/windy outside.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact I said to remove such turn knobs etc, and the spec of the problem does not including allowing people to let themselfs in.

Comment: Question did not specify. So I don't think your answer is "wrong" (I did not, and won't, downvote it) but it doesn't allow for what I (and I'm not OP, so that may not matter) consider the typical situation.

Comment: Actually any alarm which notifies me on my phone is a working solution., no need to wake up the neighbours at 3 am, in case I am going out at that time. Are such alarms available and is it easy to install one? (Btw, it is useful when you are home, but have forgotten to lock the door, too).